# How to perform SELECT query with where clause in Sqlite database of android?

Tags: android

How to get unique column of SQLite database in android using where clause.
I want to get the value from db and then compare it to other value how can I do?

Comment: Do you have an example of the schema of the database? Perhaps even an example of "I want to capture this value in this field and use it to search in this field"?

Comment: I want to capture the profile value which is stored in String where mylocation column of db isequal to currentlocation in my activity.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple steps to implement this.

1. Create a class by extending the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class. Mention the DB name, Table name, all the column names and the create and drop statements.

**AndroidOpenDbHelper:**

```
public class AndroidOpenDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns{

public static final String DB_NAME = "Test_DB";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
public static final String TABLE_NAME_TEST = "Test_Table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LOC = "Location";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
public static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_TEST+" ("+AndroidOpenDbHelper._ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"+COMMA_SEP+AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_LOC+TEXT_TYPE+COMMA_SEP+AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME+TEXT_TYPE+")";
public static final String SQL_DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_TEST;

public AndroidOpenDbHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int OldVersion, int NewVersion)
{
    db.execSQL(SQL_DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
}
}
```

2. In your MainActivity, call this class to initialize the Database and Tables.

   ```
   try
   {
       AndroidOpenDbHelper openDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
       SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = openDbHelperObj.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

       contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_LOC,Location);
       contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME,Name);

       long affectedRowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_TEST,null,contentValues);

       sqLiteDatabase.close();

   }catch(Exception err)
   {
       err.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. Finally add this on the activity where you want to retrieve and show the data.

   ```
   public static final String SQL_SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_TEST+" WHERE "+AndroidOpenDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME_LOC = +'Location';

   AndroidOpenDbHelper queryDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
       SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = queryDbHelperObj.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQL_SELECT_QUERY,null);

       if(cursor != null)
       {
           if(cursor.moveToFirst())
           {
               do
               {
                   String Location= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Location"));
                   String DestinationDB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name"));

               }while(cursor.moveToNext());
           }
       }
   ```

There could be some issues with the syntax of the query, so I suggest you to correct them and execute.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to do all this in my intent service class

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried so far. Otherwise we won't be able to help you. Please update your question with whatever you have tried so far.